# Javascript get data from within brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I understand that I can extract for example the currency ("EUR") with `order.unitPricePaid.currency`, but how do I extract for example the tax number ("GB08713331")?

Below is the data I have:

```json
{
  "unitPricePaid": {
    "currency": "EUR",
    "value": "59.00"
  },
  "formSubmission": [
    {
      "label": "User",
      "value": "Creatively"
    }, {
      "label": "Tax number",
      "value": "GB08713331"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is that data? It doesn't seem to be valid JavaScript code nor valid JSON.

Comment: @VLAZ — It's valid JSON

Comment: @Quentin not the data which was shown not a minute earlier. Definitely not the initial form of the question.

Comment: @VLAZ you can check it in the edit history. I was also confused but I edited the post and clicked tidy in the snippet editor and then this above was the result

Comment: I think the missing commas might have thrown you off, but someone edited it and fixed it now.

Comment: @Alex I saw all the versions. The first time around it didn't even have the curly brackets around the data. Then they were added but there was no commas. I would really prefer if OP made the changes instead of other people. The edit seems to be an assumption. A likely one but I've seen many a wrong assumption for "OP's code must have been this". I've made a few of those myself, too.

Comment: @Alex also, your edit renders it back to invalid code/JSON.

Comment: @VLAZ my bad have seen now that there were commatas missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
order.formSubmission[1].value
```

What this does is it looks at the "formSubmission" as an array. So, you can access each element how it is. Since "label: Tax Number" and "value: GB08713331" are in the second element of the array, you use "formSubmission[1]"

Comment: And even loop through `formSubmission`  and check if label is `Tax number` then extract its value.

Comment: True, but the he gave a fixed JSON array. If the size was unknown then your approach would be right, but I just wrote this to help simplify it for beginners.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the tax number using `Array.prototype.find` on the `formSubmission` property.

```js
const data = {
  "unitPricePaid": {
    "currency": "EUR",
    "value": "59.00"
  },
  "formSubmission": [{
    "label": "User",
    "value": "Creatively"
  }, {
    "label": "Tax number",
    "value": "GB08713331"
  }]
};

const taxNumber = data.formSubmission
  .find(field => field.label === 'Tax number').value;

console.log(`Tax number = "${taxNumber}"`);
```

Comment: Why do you use find. OP just asked how to access it so `data.formSubmission[1].value` seems to be fine

Comment: @Alex because you cannot always guarantee the order of an array in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this object:
`var order = { "unitPricePaid": { "currency": "EUR", "value": "59.00" }, "formSubmission": [{ "label": "User", "value": "Creatively" }, { "label": "Tax number", "value": "GB08713331" }] }`

the path to that value would be `order.formSubmission[1].value`. The [1] means we are accessing the element at index 1 of the array (index 0 would be the first element).